# Difficult Regex in Java, need advice

Tags: java, regex

Im trying to make a Regex in Java that can parse the following Strings

```
g1(g2,g2),g1(g2)

g1(g2(g3,g3),g2),g1(g2)

g1(g2)
```

I have been trying for hours but I cant make one that can split each example in the following classes.

```
    public class G1{

      List<G2> list;
    }

    public class G2{

      String g2;
      Set<String> g3;
    }
```

Where I need one instance of g1 for each of the groups.

Thanks

***EDIT***

Fixed the classes.

Comment: What exactly do you want to parse? `g1\(g2,g2),g1\(g2)|g1\(g2\(g3,g3),g2),g1\(g2)|g1\(g2)`?

Comment: I need and expresion that can work with the 3 examples i give, and convert them in that g1 class

Comment: Problem is quite poorly stated.  For example, how is this little class supposed to be populated from "g1(g2,g2)"?  The class seems to allow for a single g2 and multiple g3.  But this input has 2 g2, so then what?

Comment: You need to show an example of what you want to capture in each line like "`g1(g2,g2),g1(g2)` would capture `g1(g2,g2)` and `g1(g2)`"

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you have a grammar to deal with, regular expressions is not really the appropriate tool to do it, instead you're better off building a simple finite state machine to do the parsing.

Another option which *I don't recommend* for something this simple is to use ANTLR which is a tool that is designed to do this sort of parsing.  I don't recommend it because it would be overkill for the job.

Answer (score 1):

Regex is not a tool that handles recursion well.

For instance, it can't easily discern that the outer parentheses is the one you want in this line

`g1`**(**`g2(g3,g3),g2`**)**`,g1(g2)`

If you try to use a greedy regex, it would go collect the whole line `g1(g2(g3,g3),g2),g1(g2)`. If you try to go for non-greedy, it would collect `g1(g2(g3,g3)`. Regexes that might gather it are pretty shaky and can break pretty easy.

If the outer group is always called g1 and g1 is never nested within another group, you might be able to use something like this

```
g1\(.*?\)(?=,g1|$)
```

Really though, regex is not a tool for this task.

Comment: g1(g2(g3,g3),g2),g1(g2) -> thats exactly the problem i have and im trying to resolve. And sadly g1 can be any alfanumeric combination, its not static.